# Fire event on document unless element contains a specific class

Tags: jquery

Trying to get the the following to work to no avail: Fade out all elements with the class `.remove` only if whatever is being clicked on does not contain `.completed`

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.completed)', function(){
    $('.remove').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'does not contain .completed' is it another class of `.remove` or the class of the child element of `.remove`

Comment: It is another tag on the page that contains the class `.completed` So basically clicking anything except the tag with `.completed` should make `.remove` fade out

Comment: completed can exist anywhere on the document. parent, child, sibling...

Comment: are the clickable elements all of the same kind? a's? div's?

Comment: yes, they are all divs.

Answer (score 2):

I find this as a jQuery issue:

Using only `:not(.class)` it doesn't work properly. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPPQ9/)  demostrates it.

If your `.completed` elements have same tag names you can add `tagname:not("completed")` which works (Why?!).

In my example they are buttons, so the selector becomes `button:not('.completed')`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button:not(.completed)', function(e){
    $('.remove').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wPPQ9/1/)

Another solution would be to verify if the clicked element `hasClass('completed')`.

```
if ($(e.srcElement).hasClass("completed")) { return; }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wPPQ9/3/)

If all `.completed` elements are `div`s, replace the selector with `div:not('completed')`.

---

It would be good to create a issue [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/), also. And it will be solved.

Comment: Where does the OP mention buttons? He says they are all DIVs.

Comment: @DevlshOne In my example they are buttons. If they are divs replacing `button` with `div` will detect for divs.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check whether actual click target has the class completed, it cannot be done using the element filter in `on()` because of event bubbling

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).is('.completed')){
            $('.remove').remove()
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pJAwc/)

Answer (score 1):

`:not(.completed)` matches `<html>`, `<body>` and everyone else on the page.

That means the `click()` will be bound to **every element** that do not have a `.completed` class (including `<html>` and `<body>`), not just the `button`/`input`/`div` you intended .

[See what I mean in **this fiddle** (check the console).](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/wb3dq/8/)

---

Since `:not(.completed)` binds `<body>` and `<html>`, to avoid them, you'd have to:

```
:not(.completed, body, html)
```

But if your intended `button`/`input`/`div` is under a `table`, that `table` will also be bound. You'd have to avoid it with:

```
:not(.completed, body, html, table)
```

As you can see, this quickly grows. The simples approach is to narrow your selector positively:

```
.clicableDivs:not(.completed) OR input:not(.completed)
```

Whatever fits you. **Bottom line: `:not(.completed)` matches too much. Narrow it down.**

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I have a feeling that what you need to do is add `ev.stopPropagation()`, since this will keep going up through the DOM.</strike>

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.completed)', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $('.remove').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Or possibly, check to see if the target doesn't have `.completed` for a parent first like so:

```
$(document).on('click', function(ev){
    if ( ! $(ev.target).closest('.completed').length ) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        $('.remove').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing this working: http://jsfiddle.net/C5vqw/

Comment: You know that `on()` is a delegated-event handler? How is `stopPropagation()` supposed to work *after* the event has already propagated to the `document`?

Comment: I just added a link to a fiddle showing it working. The reason it works is because the delegate gets called for the target and each parent. If you use the OP's code and add a `console.log(ev.currentTarget)`, you'll see it cycles through those. If `ev.stopPropagation()` gets called, it stops moving up the tree.

Comment: I concede that point. I stopped even thinking about that one.